# If mass changes when we go in the speed of light . So it breaks law of matter which states that matter can't be created or destroy

Tags: speed-of-light, matter, states-of-matter, exotic-matter

When go at the speed of light the mass constantly started to change which is not possible if law of matter is correct

Comment: As Einstein formulated mass and energy have an equivalence. Mass can convert to energy and energy can convert to mass, neither is actually destroyed or created.

Comment: I just ate some food. My mass changed. Did I break conservation of mass? No. Because some of the energy content of the food is absorbed and used by my body, and the rest is secreted as waste.

Answer (score 1):

There is no law that says that mass cannot be created or destroyed.

But, also, the usual mass that we talk about - called **rest mass** - does not change when you go near the speed of light. There is a "special mass" called relativistic mass which does change. However, the notion of relativistic mass is optional in the sense that it's mostly an interpretation and doesn't aid in any calculations.

Comment: _mass cannot be created or destroyed_ ? You mean "matter". Do you consider matter and energy equivalent? Can energy be created/destroyed?

Comment: @josephh maybe you misread, I said that mass *can* be created and destroyed in my answer. Or else I don't understand what you are saying?

Comment: I think I was being pedantic. I have always referred to mass as a _measure_ of the amount of matter - meaning matter is not a measured quantity. Matter is anything that occupies space and has mass while mass is something that represents the amount of matter in a particular volume. So when I read what you wrote, I thought it to be no different than writing "kilograms cannot be created or destroyed". I see people use mass/matter interchangeably. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The statement "mass cannot be created or destroyed" belongs as an axiom  to classical, Newtonian mechanics. Until the twentieth century it was thought to be an axiom for models in physics. It gave us our money system based on gold, and [Archimedes principle.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle)

With [special relativity](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/conrel.html#c1)   this is no longer axiomatic. What is an axiom in special relativity is conservation of energy and momentum. It is all tied up in the [four vectors](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/vec4.html) describing all matter, not just the three vector of momentum

[image: invmass].

The "length" of this fourvector gives the invariant mass of a particle. The added four vectors of a system of particles have their own invariant mass, which is not just the sum of invariant masses as it is a vector algebra . Invariant because it does not change in Lorentz transformations, even for velocities close to the speed of light.

The old mass concept is what is now called the relativistic mass, and it is the inertial mass of $F=ma$ the closer to the speed of light the more acceleration is needed , i.e. for force, and according to the relativistic formulae the speed of light can only be reached by zero invariant mass particles. Due to the four vector algebra, adding the four vectors of two zero invariant mass particles, two photons for example,gives a non zero invariant mass, the classic example being the 135MeV pi0 which decays into two photons.

For low velocities the relativistic frame is indistinguishable from the Newtonian, that is why we are still discussing the "gold standard".